# Trying to install appium-xcuitest-driver

Tags: ios, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

Trying to install appium-xcuitest-driver

I am getting the following error:

> stderr: xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but
>   active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'

is a command line tools instance

I have xcode installed and up and running and every solution that I am coming across says to install Xcode, so I am not sure about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run sudo xcode-select -r which should automatically reset the path.

then run the following command npm install -g ios-deploy